# Run-time Error 91: object variable or with block variable not set while linking VB6 and MS access

Tags: vb6

when i run the given original code the error in below line is shown "Run-time error 91"

```
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\New Folder\prac1.mdb; Persist Security Info = False"
```

original code

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub SUBMIT_Click()
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\New Folder\prac1.mdb; Persist Security Info = False"
rs.Open "select DBTB1 from prac1", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

rs.Fields("NUMBER").Value = Text1.Text
rs.Fields("NAME").Value = Text2.Text
rs.Fields("CITY").Value = Text3.Text
MsgBox "data saved!", vbInformation
rs.Update

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not "linking" anything and MS Access is not involved here at all.  Using words inappropriately doesn't help you get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Error 91 because you have not actually created the Connection object.  Further, you will get the same error with the RecordSet.  I have updated your code to allow it to work:

```
Private Sub SUBMIT_Click()
   Set con = New ADODB.Connection
   con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\New Folder\prac1.mdb; Persist Security Info = False"
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   rs.Open "select DBTB1 from prac1", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

   rs.AddNew
   rs.fields("NUMBER").value = Text1.Text
   rs.fields("NAME").value = Text2.Text
   rs.fields("CITY").value = Text3.Text
   rs.Update
   MsgBox "data saved!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Also, please note the addition of `AddNew` prior to updating the database.